# Graph API /sites is not working for external guest users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to identify Sharepoint sites user has access to using Graph API. This is working just fine for internal users. However when we try this for external user (already guested in Azure AD), we are getting below error -

```
"error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "Item not found",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-06-20T16:28:01",
        "request-id": "cde68280-5538-40c3-af60-6602bd7c1214",
        "client-request-id": "ef1f7a56-caf4-e1f2-b2b0-57577fa96f03"
    }
}
```

We have tried to use Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and it's the same error there as well.

Comment: which API you are calling? do you provided access for particular sites item?

Comment: We are calling Graph /sites API and external user has access to the sharepoint site (granted via security group).

Comment: Could you please provide us the complete API Url which are you calling .

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

Comment: Thanks for the update Please use Get API call to count items in your sites - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?count=true , if this work , will procced further.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?count=true returned 200 success. Json response below. I can confirm user has access to Sharepoint site but it's not reflecting in below count.
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}

Comment: Thanks for confirmation Sachin, as you mentioned there is no data for sites , that why you are getting the error "itemNotFound"  , which make sense . I would like to know how you provide access to guest user ?

Comment: @vickykumar External user have been provided Sharepoint access by Azure AD security group. These groups are added to Sharepoint. Same way internal user have been provided access with but Graph API works fine for them and returns site data to which they have access to. So it's definitely a Graph thing not identifying the access for external user. Let me know if you need any further details on this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, in that case you can check the scopes for the external user by decoding the token in jwt.io , if he has Files.Read.All permission to read the content .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the /common endpoint a guest user has its own shadow tenant and wont be pointing to the AAD tenant it has been invited into, thus they cannot access resources like a normal member could, plus they have limitied default permissions and that does not include groups/site access unless they have been added to the area as a direct member.

However, if you are defining the tenant id in the authority then the above is not relevent.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I tried to do the same thing.

My workaround solution is testing with MS Graph Explorer, its worked for me, then you can code the same requests to talk to Graph API. Here are the steps:

1. Get your tenant Id using this site : https://www.whatismytenantid.com/
2. Open MS Graph Explorer like this : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=tenantId
3. Sign in to MS Graph Explorer with the guess account
4. You should see the name of your guess signed in with your tenant if not sign out and sign in again.
5. Unfortunately, You won't be able to lists the SharePoint Sites using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* (honestly I do not know why, maybe because the guest has only a Family account ? Its worked fine with a user in the same org.
6. You need to know the siteId, then you can list the document libraries, folders, files, etc...  using a request like this :  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives

I wish I can get the siteId from MS Graph Explorer for a guest user, but looks like it is not possible. BTW, doing the same on Google WorkSpace is a no brainer using shared drives, not like Microsoft at all...